# layout_rowWeight attribute not declared

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

#### (Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio 2015)

I'm trying to set up buttons side by side in a `gridlayout`, spanning evenly across the entire screen. Through searching for answers people say to use `layout_columnWeight` and `layout_rowWeight`, but these aren't available due to this:

```
The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:columnWeight' attribute is not declared
```

but it is. I read that it's not available until API 21, but I have 23 and 24 so that's not the problem.

This is my code for Main.axml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">

  <GridLayout
      android:minWidth="25px"
      android:minHeight="25px"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/gridLayout1" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/Button0" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:id="@+id/Button1" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0"
        android:id="@+id/Button2" />

  </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### EDIT:

I achieved the layout I was going for by changing a couple things.

1) I changed the `layout_width` in the `GridLayout` definition to `match_parent`
2) I took out the `layout_width` line in each button; I'm assuming this means that the default `layout_width` is set to "0dp"

I still get the "attribute not declared" warning when using `layout_columnWeight`, however, it apparently still works.

Comment: anybody know why I get this warning? I know that I can ignore it, but I want to understand it and make it go away.

Comment: I'm currently facing the exact issue, did you figured out how to fix it ?